# Stored procedures common sense pattern for dynamic query situation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I'm designing a table which could hold hundreds of thousands rows, as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages](
    [MessageID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](1022) NOT NULL,
    [Topic] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [DestinataryID] [int] NULL
)
```

Almost all of those could be filtered by users at application runtime, destinataryID being the most frequent. I did create indexes, just not everywhere. So, my work now is design a SP to optimize that. I did something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFilteredData
@Topic INT = NULL,
@DestinataryID INT = NULL,
@CreationDateStart DATETIME = NULL,
@CreationDateEnd DATETIME = NULL,
@Status BIT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ID, Number, CreationDate, Status, Message, Topic, DestinataryID FROM YourTable WHERE 1=1';

IF @DestinataryID IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL += ' AND DestinataryID = @DestinataryID';

IF @Topic IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL += ' AND Topic = @Topic';

-- more ifs

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Topic INT, @DestinataryID INT', @Topic, @DestinataryID;
END
```

My main concern is that it could start using bad execution plans, as it could be good to some requests and awful to others, when multiple possible contexts are being filtered.

Is my thing a regular way of doing these dynamic operations? Should I design a separate SP for each situation? Maybe using hints would help?

Comment: In general SQL is not good for generic type queries. In addition with SQL aside from following normal good practice you should not try to performance optimise queries in advance of having a performance issue to solve, because you can't predict the cause or solution. Further less than 1 million rows is unlikely to matter much... thats not much data.

Comment: It sounds like you are starting down the path of premature optimization. That is taking a non-traditional approach to a solution to solve a performance problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: I suggest doing some reading on "SQL kitchen sink query" and see how others have solved it, then make your own choices. Its not really a specific enough issue to be able to get an answer here.

Comment: The query you are trying to create here is a "catch all" or sometimes a "kitchen sink" query. There are dozens and dozens of examples all over this site and the rest of the internet.

Comment: Yep. Also, if you want the best chance of good performance plans you should avoid type conversions by using exactly matching data types on your columns and parameters, i.e.: `smallint` != `int`.

Comment: Well, thank you guys. I will be reading about that kitchen sink problem. I do know it sounds like premature, but we do have an old Sales table with a problem of this kind already. I just trying to prevent myself from going that way and also from studying that old thing, I guarantee you that thing is titanic already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my thing a regular way of doing these dynamic operations?

**Yes, this is the recommended way. This type of query is called a [Kitchen Sink Query](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/groups/data-driven/b/blog/posts/backtobasics-an-updated-kitchen-sink-example),** and your solution is actually a very good one.

The issue with a monolithic query with lots of `AND` `OR` logic is that it completely messes up the plan, with the server having no way to serve so many different options at once (it only has a single plan for all possible options).

The dynamic solution as you are doing is actually much *better*, because it generates a new plan for every combination of filters. (Note "combination of filters" **not** "combination of values", this is why you need to parameterize it using `sp_executesql`). The plan is tailored to the exact type of query being done, so the right indexes will be used.

Consider using an ORM in whichever client language in order to build these dynamic filters, as they are much better at this than T-SQL.

> It could start using bad execution plans, as it could be good to some requests and awful to others, when multiple possible contexts are being filtered.

Your concern about poor plans is not entirely unfounded, but you'd need to monitor your server to see what happens. Don't jump to anything until you have actual information. If you have decent indexing and mainly equality (not inequality or `LIKE`) predicates then you shouldn't have many issues.

> Should I design a separate SP for each situation?

If you see that a certain combination comes out particularly poorly and you want to tailor it then yes, it could make sense to do so. Otherwise don't bother. There is no need for a separate procedure for every possible combination.

Often filtered indexes or indexed views are a better option than just customizing the query.

> Maybe using hints would help?

That would depend on what the issue with the plan is, but generally hints should be avoided in favour of better indexing and general refactoring.

An example of that refactoring: your data types don't match your columns. Correcting that would improve

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFilteredData
  @Topic smallint = NULL,
  @DestinataryID INT = NULL,
  @CreationDateStart DATETIME = NULL,
  @CreationDateEnd DATETIME = NULL,
  @Status tinyint = NULL
AS
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. I'm already looking on the Kitchen Sink article. I will also be having a deep research on ORM vs T-SQL. I actually have been taught the opposite, 'SPs are just faster'. I' did not follow that blindly, and recently I have even more doubts about it, as SQL seems to be really unpredictable sometimes, really.

Comment: SPs can be faster as the plan cache is a bit better (eg when temp tables are involved) and there is also less data sent over the wire, but for this type of query it makes little difference.